# Access Window Azure Active Directory from web API controller to resolve user based on id (v-id)

Tags: azure-active-directory

I was trying to resolve an user in Azure web site based on his microsoft email Id (v-Id) using AAD Graph API. Please provide any samples or URLs for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RamLaki - have a look at the Graph API samples in the AzureADSamples org on Github: https://github.com/AzureADSamples.  I believe the WebApp-GraphAPI-DotNet and/or ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet C# samples demonstrate retrieving a User by UPN/email.  The Graph API doc has details on the User entity and the filterable properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974483.aspx

Comment: Actually I also referred to this and it resoled my issue. Thanks for the suggestion